# Open source alternative to Autosys?

Tags: untagged

As an alternative to Autosys, what is the best open source job scheduler? This question is a bit subjective but I'm looking for something that is widely used in production environments, has a good community, and has enterprise grade features.

Answer (score 1):

I had evaluated "[Job Scheduler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jobscheduler/)" at a former job. I don't remember specifics, but I do remember that it compared well with the commercial alternatives. They went with the commercial alternative, but not for technical reasons.

Comment: Googling led to this and I'm about to evaluate it. Were you able to test other open source job schedulers as well? If so, how did they compare?

Comment: Thats the only OSS one that was evaluated. They ended up choosing Cybermation Espresso (now from CA). There seem to be many alternatives these days: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler . You should let us know when you decide.

Comment: Yes, will try to evaluate a couple and will get post back to this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an Autosys like scheduler in Java for my client with all essential features of Auytosys like job types (box, command, file watcher), dependencies, global flags, box load etc ...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.schedulix.org/en

Schedulix is an open source platform for job scheduling. I cannot tell you if this is the "best" alternative to CA's AutoSys for your scenario, but it might be worth a shot. It's based on the [BICsuite](http://www.independit.de/en/bicsuite) enterprise scheduler.